# PARABOLIC (not panoramic) video stitching?

Tags: opencv, graphics, 3d, computer-vision, linear-algebra

I want to do something like [this](http://immersivemedia.com/demos/) but in reverse-- so that the cameras are outside and pointing inward. Let's start with the abstract and get specific:

1) Are there any TOOLS that will do this for me? How close can I get using existing software?

2) Say the nearest tool is a graphics library like OpenCV. I've taken linear algebra and have an undergraduate degree in CS but without any special training in graphics. Where should I go from there?

3) If I really am undergoing a decade-long spiritual quest of a self-teaching+programming exercise to make this happen, are there any papers or other resources that you aware of that might aid me?

Comment: Trying to clarify based on the demo (took me a minute to see the "drag here" thingy). You want this effect for moving objects in the center? In other words, you are looking for a "holographic" rendering of an object by surrounding it with cameras, then synthesize what it would look like from an arbitrary point of view. Mathematically I am not sure there is an exact solution when you have a finite number of cameras unless you apply some constraints on the solution - since there is no way to get the "view from a camera that isn't there".

Comment: Yes, "holographic", like an object movie that moves. I want to stitch between the cameras that I do have, which I would place in an arc. So i wouldnt even necessarily have vertical motion, or to completely surround the scene

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the demo you linked uses a 360° camera (see the black circle on the bottom) and does not involve stitching in any way.

About your question, are you aware of [this](http://phototour.cs.washington.edu/) work? They don't do stitching either, just blending between different views.

If you use inward views, then the objects you will observe will probably be quite close to the cameras, while standard stitching assumes that objects are far away. Close 3D objects mean high distortion when you change the viewpoint (i.e. parallax & occlusions), which makes it difficult to interpolate between two views. Hence, if you want stitching, then your main problem is to correctly handle parallax effects & occlusions between the views.

In my opinion, the most promising approach would be to do live stereo matching (i.e. dense 3D reconstruction) between the two camera images closest to your current viewpoint, and then interpolate the estimated disparities to generate an expected image. However, it's not likely to run in real-time, as demonstrated in the demo you linked, and the result could be quite ugly...

**EDIT**

You can also have a look at [this paper](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/courses/cap6412/spr2005/ECCV2002-NVS.pdf), which uses a different but interesting approach, however maybe not directly useful in your case since it requires the new viewpoint to be visible in the available images.

Comment: I agree that doing 3D (surface) reconstruction, then rendering the object from any other angles, is likely your best bet. The rendering could be done in real time using GPU acceleration, assuming that the surface rendering is not too dense (with limited number of cameras it can't be).